# Are the Munchkin original and Munchkin Guest Artist Editions identical?

Tags: munchkin

Do the "Guest Artist Edition" Munchkin packs have the exact same cards as their original counterparts, just with different art? Or do they have their own unique cards?

For example, would *Munchkin Guest Artist Edition* have the same cards included in *Munchkin*/*Munchkin Deluxe* (except obviously in a different art style)? And would *Munchkin Legends* contain the same cards that come with *Munchkin Legends Guest Art Edition* (again, merely in a differing art style)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Munchkin Guest Artist Edition is identical to Munchkin Deluxe, just with the cards and board illustrated by different artists.

From the [Munchkin: GAE web page](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/guestartists/munchkin-mcginty/):

> This Guest Artist Edition includes completely re-illustrated game cards, a new gameboard decorated with Ian McGinty's interpretation of the Munchkin world, and male and female standies for each player.

Other Munchkin properties that have Guest Artist Editions follow suit in a similar fashion.

UPDATE: I double checked with SJ Games just to flesh this answer out a bit. Their response to my twitter message was [this](https://twitter.com/sjgames/status/813775835152941057):

> They contain the same cards as their respective versions, just all new art, yes. -HS

Comment: Hey, thanks so much! Awesome research going above and beyond to confirm your answer with the creators! :)